# Combine arrays in forkJoin

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I have `forkJoin` returns multiple arrays all the same signature:

```
return forkJoin(this.appService.getData()).pipe(
      map(response =>
        response
          .map(x => x.map(y => y.data.uploads))
          .map(x => this.format(x)),
      ),
    );
```

I changed my code to that:

```
return forkJoin(this.appService.getData()).pipe(
          map(response =>
            response
              .map(x => x.map(y => y.data.uploads))
              .map(([x]) => [...x]) //produces only first array
              .map(x => this.format(x)),
          ),
        );
```

But now I am only getting the first array. Any ideas how to fix? I need to combine all arrays in to one so then my `this.format(x)` have only single array to operate on.
My `getData()` is looking like this:

```
getData(): Observable<Array<AxiosResponse<MyType>>> {

    //...

    return range(1, end - start).pipe(
      concatMap((i: number) =>
        this.http.get<MyType>(
          getUrl(getStartDate(i), getEndDate(i)),
        ),
      ),
      toArray(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: please provide this.appService.getData() defination

Comment: @FanCheung just updated with `getData()` def

Comment: if u remove      .map(([x]) => [...x])  this line will it work and I don't think u need forkJoin as your http call are already concatMap and produced an array when all finish

Comment: my `x` is an array of arrays that I want to combine in the single one

Comment: do you think you have the correct `response` array?  if so please console log it . i think you are confused with Observable operator with array operators. If you are getting an array there's no need to use observable operators